# pydantic: parse list of models with relationship

Tags: python, type-hinting, pydantic

I have this models:

```py
class Mailbox:
    def get_mails(self) -> List[Mail]:
        pass


class Mail(BaseModel):
    id: int
    attachments: List[Attachment]

    mailbox: Mailbox


class Attachment(BaseModel):
    filename: str
    size: int

    mail: Mail
```

And there is this list with dicts(mails):

```py
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "attachments": [
            {"filename": "some.txt", "size": 128},
            {"filename": "some2.txt", "size": 256}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "attachments": [
            {"filename": "some.txt", "size": 64}
        ]
    }
]
```

How make a list of `Mail` from this list of dicts?

I tried to do this, but I got 2 problems:

1. the `parse_obj_as` function (for such parsing) is deprecated, the documentation says to use `TypeAdapter`, but I could not figure it out
2. I am unable to do this due to the relationships of the models

Full code with models: https://pastebin.com/qdmNAk0S

Comment: 1) Shouldn't `Mailbox` inherit from `BaseModel` as well? 2) Is there a reason you kept the `get_mails` in your code snippet? 3) Since the `Mail.mailbox` field is required (no default), wouldn't you expect validation to fail for your example data anyway (because it has no `mailbox` keys)? 4) Without `__future__.annotations` that code (and the pastebin code) will fail due to the `List[Mail]` return annotation. **5) What versions of Python and Pydantic are you using?** Please put some more effort into creating a proper [mcve].

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg 1. The idea is not, why? If it doesn't have field data, it's for methods to work with mails. 2. To show you what I need to get List[Mail]. 3. That's why I asked this question, is it possible to make the pydantic set the relationship fields itself?. 4. I understand. I deliberately violated the sequence of classes so that you understand what I mean. 5. python 3.8, pydantic lasted.

Comment: You cannot simply declare a field to be of some custom type without specifying how it should be validated. That is why this is confusing. Have you tried running this? (Just the model definitions I mean.) Because the errors you receive should be quite enlightening. Just to be clear, you are simply asking about how you would construct instances of the `Mail`/`Attachment` models because they have a circular dependency on one another in terms of validation, right? Because I would worry about that first before thinking about how to create a `List[Mail]`.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I know that this code will lead to cyclic types, I specifically wrote it here in such a "beautiful" form, so that people would understand what I mean

Comment: But this is still two problems (at least) in one. First you might want to try and initialize a **single** `Mail` instance like this with a list of `attachments`, where each of them is missing the `mail` key. The `List[Mail]` parsing issue is totally separate from this. And that `Mailbox` thing is just distracting because it has nothing to do with these two problems, but introduces a third one (custom type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main challenge here is the circular dependency between `Mail` and `Attachment`. No validator alone can solve this because they are all stateless/class methods with no access to the model instance being initialized.

You can hack around that by defining a [`WrapValidator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#wrap-validators) for the `Attachment` in the `attachments` list of `Mail` that checks if it got some sort of mapping and simply returns (a `dict` of) it *without actually parsing/validating*.

Then you can use [`Mail.model_post_init`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/main/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_post_init) to pick those dictionaries up, set their `mail` key to the fully initialized `Mail` instance and parse them into real `Attachment` objects.

You can solve the annotation issue by using a [forward reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ForwardRef).

Lastly, [`TypeAdapter`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/type_adapter/) is very simple to use. Just pass it the type you want to validate against. The resulting object has a `validate_python` method to parse whatever data fits the specified schema.

Here is a working example:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
from typing import Any, Callable, List
from typing_extensions import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, TypeAdapter, WrapValidator


def allow_unvalidated_dict(v: Any, handler: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Any:
    if isinstance(v, Mapping):
        return dict(v)
    return handler(v)


class Mail(BaseModel):
    id: int
    attachments: List[
        Annotated["Attachment", WrapValidator(allow_unvalidated_dict)]
    ]

    def model_post_init(self, __context: object) -> None:
        for idx, attachment in enumerate(self.attachments):
            if isinstance(attachment, dict) and attachment.get("mail") is None:
                attachment["mail"] = self
                self.attachments[idx] = Attachment.model_validate(attachment)


class Attachment(BaseModel):
    filename: str
    size: int
    mail: Mail


MailList = TypeAdapter(List[Mail])
```

Demo:

```py
test_data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "attachments": [
            {"filename": "some.txt", "size": 128},
            {"filename": "some2.txt", "size": 256}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "attachments": [
            {"filename": "some.txt", "size": 64}
        ]
    }
]

validated = MailList.validate_python(test_data)
for mail in validated:
    print(mail)
```

Output:

```
id=1 attachments=[Attachment(filename='some.txt', size=128, mail=Mail(id=1, attachments=[...])), Attachment(filename='some2.txt', size=256, mail=Mail(id=1, attachments=[...]))]
id=2 attachments=[Attachment(filename='some.txt', size=64, mail=Mail(id=2, attachments=[...]))]
```

Of course you could completely omit the `WrapValidator`, if you just allowed `None` for `Attachment.mail` and set it as a default. But I understand that this may be undesirable.